# Trouble with twig syntax for discount conditions

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I'm trying to add a condition for a discount. It involves a custom date field. I want to discount anything that falls on Tuesday. I can't seem to get the twig syntax right. I've tried these two:

```
((cart.eDate|date('D')) == 'Tue')
((cart.eDate|date('D')) in ['Tue'])
```

I prefer the latter so I could add additional days if needed. Either of these work in templates. Is it because it is a custom field and the CP doesn't recognize it? Is there another approach?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested in why this didn't work...It appears that you can't include a filter in the twig statement for discount formula conditions, at least not |date() as I was using. The error message in the CP isn't so great since it is valid twig syntax, but I totally get not using filters in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing the `if` conditional?

Try this:

```
{% if cart.eDate|date('D') in ['Tue'] %}
    Tuesday's discount!
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Yea, that didn't work either, but thank you! I didn't have the 'if' because I was thinking the Order Condition Formula needed a boolean value to qualify the discount. The placeholder shows something like this: '@apple.com' in order.email

Comment: Just to elaborate a bit further, my thinking was the Condition Formula would provide a conditional that Commerce would then wrap an if around when evaluating whether to apply the discount or not. Maybe that's flawed thinking?